# How to Track the progress of the Upload by NetHttpClient in delphi 10?

Tags: delphi, httpclient, progress

Now I will send the file to my server through the `Nethttpclient` component in delphi 10, but I don't know how to track the progress when uploading. If I download the file, I can get the progress through the event `ReceiveData`. 
There are not any other useful functions or events to do it, please kindly help me to solve this problem.(only `nethttpclient`,because I don't use `Indy`)

Comment: What? Another HTTP component? Yet another good reason for interface programming. If you created and consumed only implemented interface object, you would have no problem to switch to Indy or another library or component that can report progress..

Comment: yes, but all of my code is base on nethttpclient

Comment: Just a point of detail, there is no such version as XE10

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TNetHTTPClient` simply does not expose any kind of status info during uploads, other than [`OnRequestComplete`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPClient.OnRequestCompleted) and [`OnRequestError`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.Net.HttpClientComponent.TNetHTTPClient.OnRequestError).  If you need status on the progress of uploaded data, you should switch to another HTTP library that provides the kind of progress reporting you want.

That being said, the only way I can see to get upload status with `TNetHTTPClient` is to post the file data using a `TStream`. Derive a custom class from `TFileStream` and override its `Read()` method to read the file data and report status as needed.

Comment: How to do it, please kindly give me some hint information, and I try to modify it.

Comment: @HenryXu: what you are asking for is too broad for StackOverflow. There are many HTTP libraries available, and many of them have progress reporting. Just pick one that suits your needs and change your code to use it. Why don't you want to use Indy? It is pre-installed in RAD Studio, and its HTTP component has progress events for both sending and receiving.

Comment: yes, they have progress events like indy, ics, cis and so on. one reason, I don't like use many third-part component, and another reason, all of the codes of my owned component  and my application is based on nethttpclient. I don't wish that I change the component to get one function.

Comment: and Tnethttpclient can support ssl and ipv6(build-in function)

Comment: Indey require to use `openssl` it is not a problem for windows but it is for OSX

Comment: @Wel OpenSSL can still be used on OSX, it is just not installed by default anymore, but you can still install it manually such as via Homebrew.

Comment: @RemyLebeau where I can download for OSX ? because I can not tell the user to do that

Answer (score 1):

Actually (i use Delphi v. 10.4.1) the TNetHttpClient implements a property/method named OnSendData similar to OnReciveData to manage the post stream during uploads:

```
property OnSendData: TSendDataEvent read FOnSendData write SetOnSendData;
```

base on TSendDataEvent declared in "System.Net.HttpClient.THTTPClient.Post" as procedure of object:

```
TSendDataEvent = procedure(const Sender: TObject; AContentLength: Int64; AWriteCount: Int64; var AAbort: Boolean) of object;
```

hope it is usefull